# Canon ixus 85is achieve 50mm focal length

Tags: canon, focal-length

Hi can please anyone help me. How can i achieve a 50mm focal length on my camera? On the outside of the lens there is written 6.2-18.6mm

thanks a lot

Comment: I think the duplicate should answer your question there, although be aware that your camera has a (relatively) small sensor, so has a crop factor of 5.6x, as opposed to the 1.6x or so being discussed in that question.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what you want to accomplish by "achiev[ing] a 50mm focal length"? What aspect of a 50mm focal length are you interested in?

Answer (score 0):

Because your camera has a crop factor of 5.6 if you were to set it to about 9mm it would be roughly equivalent to 50mm on a full frame camera.

Why do you want to "achieve" a 50mm focal length?